# Logging variables in different places

Tags: java, logging

my problem is about storing temporal values across different classes. Consider the two classes `A` and `B` from which we want to store information

```
public class A{
     private final double a1 = 1d;

     public double doStuff(double a2, Logger logger)
           double a3 = a2 + a1
           logger.setA3(a3);
           return a3

public class B{
     private final double b1 = 1d;

     public double doStuff(double b2, Logger logger)
           double b3 = b2 + b1
           logger.setB3(b3);
           return b3;
```

I am trying to log information about values created in class A and B in a logging class

```
public class Logger{
      private a3 = Double.NaN;
      private b3 = Double.NaN;

      public setA3(double a3){this.a3 = a3;}
      public setB3(double b3){this.b3 = b3;}
```

which will be passed both to class A and class B

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      Logger logger = new Logger();
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();

      a.doStuff(2d, logger);
      b.doStuff(2d, logger);
```

Now, with this approach there are several drawbacks:

1. The values in `Logger` are set via a setter instead of a constructor, so values might be overwritten accidentally, whereas a constructor would make the logged values immutable.
2. Distributing the logger over a bunch of classes is error-prone. It's easy to forget a value and if there is an error it can be tedious to find (Imagine instead of logging classes `A` and `B` there would be 10 classes with 20 methods each...)

The actual problem is that information that I want to store is created across different locations and at different times, i.e. the value `a3` in `a.doStuff()` has its scope limited to that method. What are your design suggestions in that case?

Note: I am aware of the logging class `org.slf4j.Logger` but I don't want to use it here.

Thank you very much for your help.
Max

Comment: Why does your logger store the values it is logging in fields? i.e. why?: `private a3 = Double.NaN;`

Comment: Have you already checked a design pattern approach?

Comment: What about an observer pattern with `java.util.Observable` ?

Comment: @weston damn I've noticed now. He's gonna have a logger for each instance of a class.

Comment: A logger is generally used to simplify output and/or modify the output (like adding the logging type, timestamp, etc), it is not just a struct that stores data to log. Also when initializing `double`s to a default value don't use `Double.NaN`, just use `0.0d`.

Comment: @van dench: I initialized to Double.NaN on purpose (e.g. checking for NaNs later on if something is done with the logger). Why do you suggest to initialize to 0.0d?

Comment: @weston: Why would you not store the values in fields? That way I can retrieve them later on

Comment: That's not logging then, it's something else. Logging is a write only mechanism. Please explain what you do with them when you retrieve them.

Comment: @tenticon Because it is a special case, it is defined as (0.0d / 0.0) and is only to be used in special math functions, here you are just using to store a value and it is better to initialize it to nothing or 0.0d which are both the same. Also to answer your question for `weston`, as I said a logger is used to simplify console output and often add on other information like timestamps or log types (info, error, trace, warn, debug, fatal), you are using it like a [struct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)).

Comment: @weston The logger could create an entry in a database as soon as all values are filled or so.

Comment: @Aaron: I did not know about `java.util.Observable`. This might be exactly what I need. Thanks very much.

Comment: It could, but, if the values are related like that, you should create a class to keep them together. Why don't you explain what you want to actually achieve here as A+B doesn't mean anything.